# How to make certificate accessible to CurrentUser\My installed on store location LocalMachine\My

Tags: c#, x509certificate, mmc

My applications uses the method *X509Store*(someStoreName). someStoreName is custom store name which will be removed. And because of this we need to access all the certificate from MY/Personal store which are installed on location LocalMachine. I provided the access to certificate in MMC for user id to make it accessible using X509Store(someStoreName). But I am still not able to find it, what should id do for finding it.

**X509Store(someStoreName,StoreLocation.LocalMachine)** this solution is working but I cant use it because of heavy dependency of X509Store(someStoreName) in our code base.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite all existing code to use `X509Store(someStoreName,StoreLocation.LocalMachine)` overload. There is no way to propagate certificate from `LocalMachine\My` to `CurrentUser\My`.

Comment: Thanks @Crypt32 for your reply. Is there any way to set store location in config ? So that code [ X509Store()] will always pick certificate from LocalMachine\My.

Comment: no, it is not possible.